# переход с php 5.3 на php 7.4 preg_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Вообщем перестал грабить с обновлением php до последней версии 
старый код работал

```html
$grab=@file_get_contents("./eset_upd/update.ver");
$grab = ereg_replace('(.*)ENGINE2]','', $grab); 
if ($grab!="") {
  eregi("versionid=([0-9\.]+)",$grab,$pocket);
  eregi("date=([0-9\.]+)",$grab,$pocket2);
  $txt=" {$pocket[1]} ({$pocket2[1]})";
}
else {
  $txt=" No connection :(";
}
```

Переделал на новый, берет первое выражение

```html
$grab=@file_get_contents("./eset_upd/update.ver");
$grab = preg_replace('/(.)ENGINE2]/','', $grab); 
if ($grab!="") {
  preg_match("#versionid=([0-9\.]+)#",$grab,$pocket);
  preg_match("#date=([0-9\.]+)#",$grab,$pocket2);
  $txt=" {$pocket[1]} ({$pocket2[1]})";
}
else {
  $txt=" No connection :(";
}
```

Ссылка на файл откуда грабит. 
http://update.eset.com/eset_upd/update.ver

Comment: `@` избегайте этого, мой вам совет. А так `ereg_` старье которое удалено в новых версиях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для глобального поиска (все вхождения) используйте [preg_match_all()](http://preg_match_all)

Учитывайте что в вашем случае, с использованием `preg_match_all()`, `$pocket[1]` и `$pocket2[1]` будут массивами

***UPD. Полная версия:***

```
$grab=@file_get_contents("./eset_upd/update.ver");    
preg_match_all('~(?<=ENGINE2]).*?(?=\[CONTINUOUS)~si', $grab, $matches);
if($matches){
    foreach($matches[0] as $k => $str){
        preg_match_all("~(?<=versionid=)[0-9\.]+~",$str,$pocket[$k]);
        preg_match_all("~(?<=date=)[0-9\.]+~",$str,$pocket2[$k]);
    }
    $txt = "";
    for ($i=0;$i<count($pocket);$i++){ 
        $txt .= " {$pocket[$i][0][0]} ({$pocket2[$i][0][0]}) ";
    }
} else {
  $txt=" No connection :(";
}
```

Comment: Я не программист, как $pocket[1] и $pocket2[1] загнать в массив для функции preg_match_all().

Comment: Нет, я имел ввиду что функция возвратит 2 массива эти, чтобы работало как раньше надо написать по-другому. Как у вас выводились данные? Пример напишите.

Comment: выввод был 20567 (25.12.2019),  сейчас 1031 (28,05,2019), то бишь номер базы и дату её. Нужно для сравнения баз актуальная или нет, чтобы скрипт не гонять просто  так. Спасибо

Comment: И пример входной строки ($grab) напишите

Comment: $grab=@file_get_contents("./eset_upd/update.ver");

Comment: Нет, уже строку которая тут записывается можете написать?

Comment: http://update.ikt-pro.ru/update.txt - вот перевел в текст входные данные.

Comment: Ok. Нужно брать только последний найденный эл-т или выводить все найденные версии с датами?

Comment: Должен найти                                                                                       [ENGINE2]
version=20567 (20191225)
versionid=20567
build=43890
type=engine
category=engine
level=2
base=43677
date=25.12.2019
platform=x86
group=perseus,ra,core
buildregname="EngineBuild"
file=/v3-rel-sta/mod_002_engine_43890/em002_32_l2.nup
size=643151                                                                                                                               из этого взять номер базы и дату 20567 (25,12,2019) по идеи он найдет 2 элемента и они одинаковые